# Store bitmap in text file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to store small bitmaps in a text file similar to the  way Delphi does it with it's `dfm` files.

Is there a function in the RTL or VCL that I could use to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest that you do the following:

1. Save to an in memory stream. Use TMemoryStream, and call SaveToStream on the bitmap.
2. Compress the stream, perhaps using the zlib unit. This step is optional.
3. Encode the stream using base64. For example you can use the functionality provided by Soap.EncdDecd.

And in the opposite direction, well you just reverse the steps.

Answer (score 3):

Textual DFMs use the `BinToHex()` function to format binary data.

Comment: Simplicity and backwards compatibility, I imagine. Its not like the textual output is used by the actual compiled executable, because it is not.  It is only used by the IDE and compiler, so it is easier to parse simple hex than some other compressed format. Storage space is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Win32.WriteFile to write your bitmap-buffer into a file.

Comment: This will write binary data...I specifically asked about text files

Comment: I seeeee! Then David's solution is just perfect!